# Convert a tableview javafx value to a 2Darray of double

Tags: arrays, javafx, tableview, fxml, observablelist

I'm quite rusty on JavaFX and I have this problem killing my brain for a couple of days. I am able to load an excel file into a `TableView` using the *gembox.spreadsheet* API and can edit those values as well. I got something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxeBd.png). What I want is to get the entire `TableView` content into a 2D array of `double` for further calculations.
I tried something like the following, which builds fine but on running it I get `java.lang.NullPointException` error.

```
double [][] offset = new double[OffsetTable.getItems().size()][];

for(int row = 0; row < OffsetTable.getItems().size(); row++) {
    ObservableList cells =(ObservableList) OffsetTable.getItems().get(row);
    for(int column = 0; column < cells.size(); column++) {
        offset[row][column]= Double.parseDouble(cells.get(column).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of the code (that you posted in your question) is throwing `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Thank you @Abra.the inner for loop :offset[row][column]=Double.parseDouble(cells.get(column).toString());

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a two-dimensional array is really an array of arrays. You instantiate the array of arrays, `offset`, but you never instantiate the individual arrays that it contains.

Thus when you try to assign to element `column` of array `offset[row]` with

```
offset[row][column] = ... ;
```

you get a `NullPointerException`, because `offset[row]` hasn't been initialized and is still `null`.

You need to do something like

```
double[][] offset = new double[offsetTable.getItems().size()][];

for(int row = 0; row < offsetTable.getItems().size(); row++) {
    ObservableList cells =(ObservableList) offsetTable.getItems().get(row);
    offset[row] = new double[cells.size()];
    for(int column = 0; column < cells.size(); column++) {
        offset[row][column]= Double.parseDouble(cells.get(column).toString());
    }
}
```

---

Note that it looks like your `TableView` is not very well set up. You should never use raw types (`ObservableList`), and I can't ever see a reason to make the row of a `TableView` itself observable. Additionally, to populate the array, you are converting the value in the table to a `String` and then parsing the `String` to a double, which is at best highly inefficient but also error-prone.

So instead of a `TableView<ObservableList>` you should probably have something like a `TableView<List<Double>>`, so you could then do

```
double[][] offset = new double[offsetTable.getItems().size()][];

for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < offsetTable.getItems().size(); rowIndex++) {
    List<Double> row = offsetTable.getItems().get(rowIndex);
    offset[rowIndex] = new double[row.size()];
    for(int column = 0; column < row.size(); column++) {
        offset[row][column]= row.get(column);
    }
}
```

In fact, with this setup, it's not even clear you'd need to convert to an array at all, since you can always replace

```
offset[row][column]
```

with

```
offsetTable.getItems().get(row).get(column)
```

any time you need to access data in the table.

Comment: @AustineAdah You should accept the answer if it is correct.